# directx compiling issue need advice

Tags: directx

Can someone correct my code here on why it's not compiling

I get these errors

```
bloomShader.cpp(10) : error C2660: 'D3DXAssembleShaderFromFileA' : 
function 
does not take 5 arguments
bloomShader.cpp(11) : error C2227: left of '->CreatePixelShader' must 
point 
to class/struct/union
    type is ''unknown-type''
bloomShader.cpp(13) : error C2227: left of '->SetPixelShader' must point 
to 
class/struct/union
    type is ''unknown-type''
```

Here is my code where I get these errors I am trying to compile this please help with some examples on how to properly do this thanks.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "B:\Program Files (x86)\Sierra\FEAR Public Tools 
v2\Source\Game\ClientShellDLL\includes\d3dx9shader.h"
#include "B:\Program Files (x86)\Sierra\FEAR Public Tools 
v2\Source\Game\ClientShellDLL\includes\d3d9.h"
#include "B:\Program Files (x86)\Sierra\FEAR Public Tools 
v2\Source\Game\ClientShellDLL\includes\d3dx9.h"

// here is my identifiers for my maker shader method
DWORD m_hPixelShader;
LPD3DXBUFFER pCode;
int g_pd3dDevice;
int hRes;
int lpErrorMsgs;
int pErrorMsgs;
int g_lpDevice;
int lpPixelShader;


void MakeShader(void) {
D3DXAssembleShaderFromFile("B:\\Program Files (x86)\\Sierra\\FEAR Public 
Tools 
v2\\Source\\Game\\ClientShellDLL\\shaders\\bloom.txt",0,NULL,&pCode,NULL);
g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader( (DWORD*)pCode->GetBufferPointer(),
      &m_hPixelShader );
g_pd3dDevice->SetPixelShader( m_hPixelShader );
// here is where we check for assenmpled shader errors
if ((FAILED(hRes)) && (lpErrorMsgs != NULL))
{
unsigned char* message = (unsigned char*)pErrorMsgs->GetBufferPointer();

// Other error handling here. 
}
// here is where the pixel shader is created
hRes = g_lpDevice->CreatePixelShader((DWORD*)pCode->GetBufferPointer(), 
                                     &lpPixelShader);
if (FAILED(hRes)) return false;

hRes = g_lpDevice->SetPixelShader(lpPixelShader);
if (FAILED(hRes)) return false;
}
```

Also, any code examples you could provide me on how I need to do this I am better at reading code thanks

Comment: You should probably be including ``d3dx9.h``. You also haven't defined ``g_pd3dDevice`` or created a Direct3D 9 device.

Comment: Umm, I added the d3dx9.h and I also defined the g_pd3dDevice so the last thing is the Direct3D 9 Device any example on this function thanks

Comment: [legacy Direct3D 9 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/dx9-graphics)